# Ghost images show up when drawing rect with double buffering tech in PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

Here is my code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QPoint
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget


class Demo(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Demo, self).__init__()
        self.resize(600, 600)

        self.pix = QPixmap(600, 600)
        self.pix.fill(Qt.white)

        self.begin_point = QPoint()
        self.end_point = QPoint()

    def paintEvent(self, QPaintEvent):
        painter = QPainter(self)

        x = self.begin_point.x()
        y = self.begin_point.y()
        w = self.end_point.x()-x
        h = self.end_point.y()-y
        painter2 = QPainter(self.pix)       # paint on a QPixmap first
        painter2.drawRect(x, y, w, h)
        painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, self.pix)  # then pain on the widget

    def mousePressEvent(self, QMouseEvent):
        if QMouseEvent.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.begin_point = QMouseEvent.pos()
            self.end_point = self.begin_point

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, QMouseEvent):
        if QMouseEvent.buttons() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.end_point = QMouseEvent.pos()
            self.update()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    demo = Demo()
    demo.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The slower I move, the more ghost images of rect I get(left one is the slower one).

[image]

First I hope my code shows a correct understanding in double buffering tech. Please point it out if not.

I know it is caused by too many calls of paintEvent(). I want to know how to make it right without deleting mouseMoveEvent() because I want the users to see the rect all the time when they are drawing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In these cases it is to have 2 types of data that store different types of information: permanent and temporary information. In the case of the permanent, it must be the rectangle after releasing the mouse, saving it in the QPixmap, and the temporary one must be drawn while dragging the mouse.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Demo(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Demo, self).__init__()
        self.resize(600, 600)

        self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap(600, 600)
        self.pix.fill(QtCore.Qt.white)
        self.begin_point, self.end_point = QtCore.QPoint(), QtCore.QPoint()

    def paintEvent(self, QPaintEvent):
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        painter.drawPixmap(QtCore.QPoint(), self.pix)

        if not self.begin_point.isNull() and not self.end_point.isNull():
            r = QtCore.QRect(self.begin_point, self.end_point)
            painter.drawRect(r.normalized())

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() & QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.begin_point = event.pos()
            self.end_point = self.begin_point
            self.update()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.buttons() & QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.end_point = event.pos()
            self.update()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() & QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            r = QtCore.QRect(self.begin_point, self.end_point)
            painter = QtGui.QPainter(self.pix)
            painter.drawRect(r.normalized())
            self.begin_point = self.end_point = QtCore.QPoint() 
            self.update()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    demo = Demo()
    demo.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: thank you agian, but I don't understand this line in painEvent(), why should we draw it first? What's the purpose?                                   
painter.drawPixmap(QtCore.QPoint(), self.pix)

Comment: @la_vie_est_belle in paintEvent when redrawing it eliminates the previous thing, that is to say it does not have memory so if you want to draw several rectangles you can only do it one, then how can we have something permanent? you can use a data to keep the information, and in this case it is the QPixmap is the right one. So we just add the rectangle to the permanent memory (QPixmap) and paint the temporary in the paintEvent + Pixmap = temporary + permanent.

Comment: appreciate your help